# AxiosError: Network Error react native android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, express, axios

I try a sign up with NodeJS express and react native but when I get my request with `axios` I have the error:

> AxiosError: Network Error

```
const Signin = props => {
  const [nom, setNom] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [solde, setSolde] = useState(200);
  const [titre, setTitre] = useState('client');

  const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001';

  const onSignUp = (nom, email, password, solde, titre) => {
    axios
      .post(`${baseUrl}/api/signIn`, {
        nom: nom,
        email: nom,
        solde: solde,
        titre: solde,
        password: solde,
      })
      .then(res => {
        let usrInfo = res.data;
        console.log(usrInfo);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
};
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: May I ask your axios version? And the error code is 400 or 500?

Comment: add this flag in you android manifest file `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`